# Not able to use azure test plans even after enabling trial for "Basic + Test plan"

Tags: azure-devops

i have enabled "Basic + Test plan" trial or the organization, to use test plans in azure. But still it is showing basic functionalities with a message in the screen.
Error: You are currently logged in as a user with basic access level and you are seeing this page as you don't have any test plans and test suites created for the selected team.
[Org setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNaOB.png)

[Accessing test plans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZw4V.png)

Answer (score 3):

According to the description in the document "[**Try Azure Test Plans for free**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/billing/try-additional-features-vs?view=azure-devops)", during the free trial of Test Plans, the users who are **`Basic`** or **`Basic + Test Plans`** access level can access Test Plans.

However, according to my test, only the **`Basic + Test Plans`** can access Test Plans. I have created an issue to report this (see [MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs#10826](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/10826)).

So, you can navigate to "**`Organization Settings`**" > "**`Users`**" to check whether you are **`Basic + Test Plans`** access level.

[image]

If you are not this access level, you need to contact the **`Organization Owner`** or **`Project Collection Administrators`** to assign you this access level.

[image]